# docker swarm service using the same VIP

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

We are running docker version  17.06.0-ce and I'm very new to docker (at present learning it on the fly with little network/linux knowledge/experience).

One of the environment we have is running a single manager and worker.
What we are seeing the following two scenarios occurring :
- services are being assign a VIP that is being used and the service will fail to start with "Address already in use" error.
- services starts and is using the same VIP as another service.  This can been seen on the manager "docker service inspect".  This cause nginx to send requests to the wrong service (this can be seen in the logs).

Several question:
1) Has anyone encounter this?
2) how to does docker swarm decide on what VIP to assign?
3) How does docker know which VIP to use in a multi worker environment?  The reason I ask is because in a single manager/worker environment you can see the VIP on the manager "docker service inspect" is the same as the worker "docker network inspect ingress" but in a multi manager/worker environment the VIP are all different.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you mustn't use VIP. You have to work just with the name of services, and docker swarm will manage the load balancing.

Comment: I'm not using VIP.  This is what I'm seeing inside docker.  What I'm using is NGINX sending traffic to service via DNS:Port.

Comment: But VIPs are defined in config files or Nginx assign VIPs alone

Comment: [Docker Reference Architecture: Designing Scalable, Portable Docker Container Networks](https://success.docker.com/article/Docker_Reference_Architecture-_Designing_Scalable,_Portable_Docker_Container_Networks) States "Internal load balancing is instantiated automatically when Docker services are created. When services are created in a Docker Swarm cluster, they are automatically assigned a Virtual IP (VIP) that is part of the service's network. The VIP is returned when resolving the service's name." under heading "Docker Native Load Balancing"

Comment: It looks like it's a docker bug according to https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34163